# Calculate mean difference per row and per group

Tags: r, grouping, mean, difference

I have a `data.frame` with many rows and columns and I want to calculate the mean difference of each value to each of the other values within a group.
Here an example:

```
 ID  value 
 1    4 
 1    5 
 1    7 
 2    8 
 2    6 
 2    5 
 2    6
```

This is what I want to calculate:

```
ID  value  value_mean_diff 
 1    4     (4-5)^2 + (4-7)^2 /groupsize = 3
 1    5     (5-4)^2 + (5-7)^2 / 3
 1    7     (7-4)^2 + (7-5)^2 / 3
 2    8     (8-6)^2 + (8-5)^2 + (8-6)^2 / 4
 2    6     (6-8)^2 + (6-5)^2 + (6-6)^2 / 4
 2    5     (5-8)^2 + (5-6)^2 + (5-6)^2 / 4
 2    6     (6-8)^2 + (6-6)^2 + (6-5)^2 / 4
```

I tried using aggregate() but failed to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution using `crossjoin` in `data.table` library with a defect of removing the duplicated row from the original data frame:

```
> dt <- setDT(df)[,setNames(CJ(value, value), c("value", "value1")), .(ID)][,.(value_mean_diff = sum((value-value1)^2)/.N),.(ID, value)]
> dt
   ID value value_mean_diff
1:  1     4        3.333333
2:  1     5        1.666667
3:  1     7        4.333333
4:  2     5        2.750000
5:  2     6        1.250000
6:  2     8        4.250000
```

Since duplicated rows always have the same `value_mean_diff`, you can always merge them to get all the duplicated rows.

```
> merge(dt, df, by = c("ID", "value"))
   ID value value_mean_diff
1:  1     4        3.333333
2:  1     5        1.666667
3:  1     7        4.333333
4:  2     5        2.750000
5:  2     6        1.250000
6:  2     6        1.250000
7:  2     8        4.250000
```

**Update**:
Since the above method is memory intensive, you can take advantage of the fact that your *value_mean_diff = (value - value_mean)^2 + variance(value)*, which you can prove by expanding the variance based on its definition. With this as a fact, you can calculate by the following way:

```
> setDT(df)[, value_mean_diff := (value - mean(value))^2 + var(value) * (.N - 1) / .N, .(ID)]
> df
   ID value value_mean_diff
1:  1     4        3.333333
2:  1     5        1.666667
3:  1     7        4.333333
4:  2     8        4.250000
5:  2     6        1.250000
6:  2     5        2.750000
7:  2     6        1.250000
```

Keep in mind that the `var()` function in R calculate the sample variance so you need to convert it to population variance by multiplying a factor **(n-1)/n**.

Comment: Hello @Psidom, thanks for the answer. I tried using your code my dataframe but i'm not sure i understand how it works.  `dt = setDT(train_data)[,setNames(CJ(train_data$distance, train_data$distance), c("value", "value1")), .(train_data$srch_id)][,.(value_mean_diff = sum((value-value1)^2)/.N),.(train_data$srch_id, train_data$distance)]`  Results in a memory error: cannot allocate vector of size 74.5 Gb

Comment: Not sure how large is your data.frame. `dt = setDT(train_data)[,setNames(CJ(distance, distance), c("distance", "distance1")), .(srch_id)][,.(value_mean_diff = sum((distance-distance1)^2)/.N),.(srch_id, distance)]`

Comment: Thanks again, I got 100.000 rows. It still gives me a memory error this way. Error: cannot allocate vector of size 37.3 Gb

Comment: As it says, we have a memory issue. The method tends to fast but also memory intensive. If the performance is not a issue, you can try the answer given by @Dominic.

Comment: Thanks for the effort

Comment: This works like a charm! Got the results that I want and it is finished within a couple of seconds. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using only base R:

```
myData <- data.frame(ID=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2), value=c(4,5,7,8,6,5,6), diff=NA)
for(i in 1:nrow(myData))
    myData$diff[i] <- with(data = myData,
        sum((value[i] - value[ID==ID[i]])**2)/length(value[ID==ID[i]]))

myData

  ID value     diff
1  1     4 3.333333
2  1     5 1.666667
3  1     7 4.333333
4  2     8 4.250000
5  2     6 1.250000
6  2     5 2.750000
7  2     6 1.250000
```

Comment: Hello Dominic, thanks a lot for your solution, it worked! It took 3 min a 3 seconds to execute for 100.000 rows. I'm very happy that it worked, thanks again.